# Flutter: Prevent Margin Clipping

Tags: listview, user-interface, dart, flutter, margin

I have a horizontal `ListView.builder`. The image attached demonstrates my UI.

The `listView` (red). `itemBuilder` button widgets (blue); The margin (green).

[image]

When the list is scrolled to the edge, without a margin, my button will be visibly against the edge of the screen.

If I add a `margin` or `padding` via a `Container` or the `ListView`, it moves my UI in as expected.

However, when I scroll my list, items in the list are now clipped by this margin and do not scroll to the edge of the screen, but the margin boundary.

How can I have an inset that doesn't clip my list when scrolling?

Comment: Add a dummy padding widget (or sizedbox, or container, ...) as the first item in the list? I'd normally do this with padding on the list items themselves.

Comment: use `clipBehavior: Clip.none` in `ListView.builder`

Answer (score 25):

`ListView` possess a `padding` property for that purpose.

The following code will offset the first element by 8. But that padding won't clip the list content, as opposed to wrapping `ListView` inside a `Padding`.

```
   ListView.builder(
      padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 8.0),
      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
        return Container(
          height: 42.0,
          color: index % 2 == 0 ? Colors.red : Colors.blue,
        );
      },
    ),
```

Comment: This is not the case with horizontal scrolling and left/right padding.

Comment: I tested it on both axis, with and without reverse, and it does work.

Comment: If it doesn't work for you either submit a bug or add your code here. Because that shouldn't be. `padding` of `listview` exists only to _not_ clip it's children.